# Where to add kernal_regularizers in an U-net?

Tags: keras, neural-network, computer-vision

I am using the u-net code from this [Kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/keegil/keras-u-net-starter-lb-0-277?scriptVersionId=2164855) that I've also pasted below:

```
inputs = Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
s = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255) (inputs)

c1 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (s)
c1 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c1)
p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c1)

c2 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (p1)
c2 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c2)
p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c2)

c3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (p2)
c3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c3)
p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c3)

c4 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (p3)
c4 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c4)
p4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)) (c4)

c5 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (p4)
c5 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c5)

u6 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c5)
u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
c6 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (u6)
c6 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c6)

u7 = Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c6)
u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
c7 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (u7)
c7 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c7)

u8 = Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c7)
u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
c8 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (u8)
c8 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c8)

u9 = Conv2DTranspose(8, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c8)
u9 = concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
c9 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (u9)
c9 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c9)

outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[mean_iou])
```

My question is where to properly add a [kernal_regularizer](https://keras.io/regularizers/) (l2 regularization). I've looked at countless repos and notebooks, but I'm not able to find any source where l2 regularization was used successfully. Although I know how l2 regularization works, I have no intuition about which layers to add it into.

Hence, some intuition on where to add the kernal regularizer and what to set the param to would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going over the Kaggele notebook you have linked. It appears that no weight regularization is being used throughout the entire model (so the code you added is correct).

This is quit peculiar and very uncommon, in almost all cases and models, L2 weight regularization (a.k.a ridge regression) is being used in every single layer, perhaps just with different weight-decay coefficients.

I suggest adding weight regularization to all the layers but starting with a very small weight decay coefficient:

```
c1 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(w_decay)) (s)
c1 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(w_decay)) (c1)
p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c1)
...
```